# bootstrap modal data-backdrop= false allow close modal outside click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `bootstrap 3`. I used `modal` and `set data-backdrop = false`. Now i `want to close the modal outside clicking of modal`.

I tried to handle manually and works wanted to know is there any default setting to close with `data-backdrop=false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$('#myModal').modal({
  backdrop: true
})
```

Comment: I don't want to use backdrop. i am facing issue with `backdrop:false`